# Does Office 2016 and Office 2016 under O365 use same Interop DLL's

Tags: office365, office-interop, office-2016

Our Windows Citrix based application is migrating from Office 2010 to Office 2016 . We have built our application using Office 2016 software. During Server deployment , Infra teams are saying they do not have Office 2016 and they have Office 365 only. Now O265 is cloud subscription and it has Office 2016 . I believe All interop DLL's used are same . Will my application work if we install Office 365 in server ?

Comment: This actually was previously answered on the Microsoft Office boards through Microsoft.

[Does office 365 online version support vba](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c46823c-2581-47a6-baac-66fb99ac3ea8/does-office-365-online-version-supports-vbavisual-basic-for-applications?forum=Office2016ITPro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 users may get updates more frequently (depends on the channel chosen), so there can be a difference.

Anyway, your application can work even with earlier interop versions unless new properties or methods (members) are used. There is no requirement to use a corresponding interop version.